# I am having a problem in adding sideshow in the website need CSS code

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-deployment

I have the HTML of the code but need the CSS I am average at CSS I am creating a website for
wallpapers so need a  definite slideshow at the home of the page with a slide> button with CSS HTML
javascript and it must be the home of the page and responsive in all the devices if you need
any reference comment down below for any doubts and write code in a way that all understand it
because  a fool can write code which a machine understands
but a great programmer code which humans understand
correct me if I am wrong

HTML code -

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <!-- Image text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnail images -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

need CSS for it

Comment: Question with "give me the codez" are not really welcomed in Stackoverflow, So please show what you have tried instead of "give me a proper code now", You cant expect someone to write a perfect code for you if you didnt put any efforts in this, also this phrase is not needed: "*and write code in a way that all understand it because a fool can write code which a machine understands but a great programmer code which humans understand correct me if I am wrong*". Anyways Goodluck and regards

Comment: Another point is please review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. In this case, this question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Visit: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp for a better and simpler way of creating slideshows

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
var index = 0;


function prevSlide(n){
  index+=n;
  console.log("prevSlide is called");
  changeSlide();
}

function nextSlide(n){
  index+=n;
  changeSlide();
}

changeSlide();

function changeSlide(){
    
  if(index>slides.length-1)
    index=0;
  
  if(index<0)
    index=slides.length-1;
  
  
  
    for(let i=0;i<slides.length;i++){
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      
      dots[i].classList.remove("active");
      
      
    }
    
    slides[index].style.display = "block";
    dots[index].classList.add("active");

  

}
```

```css
body{
  background:#e6e6e6;
}
#slider{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);;
}

.slide{
  width:100%;
  
  display:none;
  animation-name:fade;
  animation-duration:1s;
  
}
img{
 width:100%; 
}
@keyframes fade{
  from{opacity:0.5;}
  to{opacity:1;}
}

.controls{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding:15px 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  
}

.controls:hover{
  background:white;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.controls:active{
  color:grey;
}

#left-arrow{
  left:10px;
}

#right-arrow{
  right:10px;
}

#dots-con{
  
  text-align:center;
}
.dot{
  display:inline-block;
  background:grey;
  padding:8px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:10px 5px;
}

.active{
  background:crimson;
}

@media (max-width:576px){
  #slider{width:100%;
  
  }
  
  .controls{
    font-size:1em;
  }
  
  #dots-con{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <!--Slider-->
<div id="slider">  
  <div class="slide" style="background:dodgerBlue;">
    <img src="https://img.fotocommunity.com/peacefull-95e65145-d050-4957-9ddc-85dd60689d45.jpg?height=500" >
  </div>
  
  <div class="slide" style="background:coral;">
     <img src="https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/images-profile-flow/400/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/2/sunset-storm-haystack-rock-canon-beach-oregon-coast-tl-mair.jpg" >
  </div>
 
  <div class="slide" style="background:crimson;">
    <img src=" https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/images-profile-flow/400/images-medium-large-5/1-tourists-at-eiffel-tower-paris-panoramic-images.jpg" >
  </div>
  
  <div class="slide" style="background: #6edf10;">
    <img src="https://dmasia.travel/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vit3-1000x350.jpg" >
  </div>
  
  <!--Controlling arrows-->
  <span class="controls" onclick="prevSlide(-1)" id="left-arrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
  <span class="controls" id="right-arrow" onclick="nextSlide(1)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
</div>
  <div id="dots-con">
 <span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span>
 </div>
```